# How to map specific .onion addresses to static local virtual IP address?

Tags: debian, ssh, ip-address

I noticed that when using iptables_torify to force connections through TOR that .onion addresses are mapped to local virtual IPs in the 10.66.x.x range.  This is indicated in the torrc file:

```
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.66.0.0/255.255.0.0
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
```

Unfortunately, TOR is constantly assigning different IPs to the same hidden service which is causing a few problems.  For example:

> Whenever I use my local ssh client to connect to a hidden service I
>   get some kind of message like:
>
> > The authenticity of host 'blahblahblahblah.onion (10.66.51.17)' can't
> >     be established.  ECDSA key fingerprint is 0a:1b:2c:..... Are you sure
> >     you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
>
> Now if I click yes all is good until next time I reboot the computer I
>   get the same message again with a different address (eg:
>   10.66.172.189).  Sometimes I get an address that was already used for a different hidden service and I have to go to ~/.ssh/know_keys to
>   delete the line in question before I can connect.
>
> I really need to be able to just tell tor to permanently map address
>   blahblahblah.onion to let's say 10.66.10.10. That way I could just ssh
>   10.66.10.10 and have the ssh fingerprint for 10.66.10.10 listed once and for all in my ~/.ssh/knownhosts file.

Thank you Linostar for suggesting:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host
```

However SSH is only one of my problems that I showed for illustration purposes.  And actually I would like to use the .ssh/known_keys file to verify the keys of the servers I'm connecting to rather than just blindly connecting to the server.

I also need to use other programs that may only give the option of specifying an IP address for outgoing connections.  For example, if I want to tell FireFox to connect to a proxy server (the proxy server has a .onion address).  I'm sure there's a work around for that too but just specifying the ip address would be a lot simpler for me.

Anyway, I don't want to rely on iptables to send DNS requests to TOR when it would be a lot simpler and more secure to just specify the ip address of the hidden service.  On some servers I'm unable to configure iptables anyway.  And I don't want to take the risk of a DNS leak in case I made an error configuring iptables or if the configuration was changed without my knowledge.

All that to say that mapping an .onion address to a specific IP would be a very important benefit that would save a lot of trouble for nothing.  Hopefully somebody has a solution!

Comment: You should be able to use an onion address as a proxy in Firefox. Remember that local virtual IP addresses are meant to be temporary, and the benefits from making them static can be found elsewhere (or so I think).

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any method to map .onion addresses to local IP addresses like you described, so I am going to propose an alternative approach.

When connecting to an onion SSH service, use the following command syntax:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host
```

That will make ssh bypass the KnownHosts files and not ask for fingerprint checking anymore, which is kind of useless when you have an ever-varying service IP address.

To make things easier, you can make an alias of the command above. For example:

```
alias sshtor='ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

and place that alias line in your ~/.bashrc, so you can connect to onion SSH servers by typing:

```
sshtor user@host
```